# Styling OpenLayers 5 Vector dynamically

Tags: javascript, openlayers, jquery

I have a checkbox button, and I am trying to change the variable `getStyle` dynamically, when jQuery `change` event is triggered. Though style property doesn't get updated when the event is triggered.

```
var style1= new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'khaki'
      }),
       stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#880000',
          width: 2,
          opacity:1
        })
    });

    var style2= new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#5755d900'
      }),
       stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'yellow',
          width: 2,
          opacity:1
        })
    });

     var getStyle = style1; //default style


    $("#layerbg").change(function () { 
      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        getStyle = style2; //change style when checkbox is ticked
      }
      else{
        getStyle = style1;
      }
    });

    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
      style:getStyle, // this variable (getStyle) is not updating
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: 'JS/getjson.json',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
       }),opacity: 1
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will use the value of `getStyle` at the time `vector` is defined.  For dynamic styling you need a style function

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  style: function(){ return getStyle; },
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'JS/getjson.json',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
   }),
   opacity: 1
});
```

or you could use `vector.setStyle(getStyle);`